# Algebraic context for Mednykh's formula?

Tags: gr.group-theory, surfaces, quantum-topology

Let $S$ be a closed orientable surface and let $G$ be a finite group, then Mednykh's formula says that
$$
\sum_{V}d(V)^{\chi(S)} = |G|^{\chi(S) - 1} |\text{Hom}(\pi_1 S, G)|
$$
where the sum is over isomorphism classes of irreducible representations of $V$ of $G$ and $d(V)$ is the dimension of $V$.  There is also a version of this theorem for nonorientable closed surfaces where in the sum, each representation must be weighted by its Frobenius-Schur indicator of the reprentations.  The cases of $S = S^2, T^2, \mathbb{R}P^2$ give some nice formulas that are natural to state with no mention of topology.

I am a bit familiar with this formula from the quantum topology perspective but I was wondering to what extent there are generalizations of this formula where $\pi_1 S$ is replaced by a more general group (like for example a general 1-relator group) and $\chi(S)$ is replaced by something.  For example, is there any version of this formula for $\pi_1(S)$ replaced by $\mathbb{Z}/3$?

I'm essentially wondering: when a group theorist sees Mednykh's formula, is it a special case of something valid for groups more general than surface groups?

Comment: Interesting question! However, I do not think such a formula should exist for $\mathbb Z/3$, at least if you want "$\chi(S)$" to depend only on "$\pi_1(S)$". If we plug in $G$ which does not have elements of order 3 then I suppose the only uniform option for $\chi(S)$ should be 2. But then if you plug in some $G$ which has elements of order 3 you are screwed..

Comment: You ask about one-relator groups. It might be instructive to think about Baumslag's example $\langle a,b\mid a^ba(a^b)^{-1}=a^2\rangle$: $a$ dies in every finite quotient, so every finite quotient is cyclic.

Comment: I don’t think you should expect such a thing. This formula comes from combining that 2d local TFTs exactly correspond to semisimple algebras and that C[G] is a semisimple algebra with two natural bases.  To generalize this you’d want something like a TFT which makes sense for simplicial complexes instead of just manifolds.  You just wouldn’t expect those to be classified by algebras.

Comment: I could imagine explicit formulae for things like 1-relator groups; however one does not expect "nice" formulas for the number of representations in general (for arbitrary finitely presented groups) because residual finiteness is undecidable. On the other hand, for $\mathbb{Z}/3$ one can probably get some sort of formula in terms of the character table of the group. For each conjugacy class, one may extract the size of the conjugacy class (from the order of the centralizer of an element) and the order. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_table#Properties